# python3 find value inside array inside another array

Tags: python-3.x

I have my array is  : `Li = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` how can check if value exist in an array . Example

```
if 5 exist in Li return Li[1][1] so I can change the value of that item by making Li[1][1]= 
"X"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *nested list* is always a 2D matrix of numbers, then you can find the indices fairly easily:

```
def find_indices(nested_list, value):
    
    for i, inner_list in enumerate(nested_list):
        for j, item in enumerate(inner_list):
            if item == value:
                return (i,j) # return a tuple containing the indices

Li = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(find_indices(Li, 5))
```

This example uses the enumerate function in Python, which gives you the index and item inside of an iterable object.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it is hard to understand what u really want, or if u urself even know that. Here is some input that might help u:

```
from typing import List


def is_value_in_list_of_lists(
    value_to_check: int, list_of_lists: List[List[int]]
) -> bool:
    for v in list_of_lists:  # v::List[int]
        if value_to_check in v:
            return True
    return False

def replace_all_occurrences_of_value_in_list_of_lists(
    value_to_check: int, value_to_replace_with: str, list_of_lists: List[List[int]]
) -> List[List[int]]:
    if is_value_in_list_of_lists(value_to_check, list_of_lists):
        modified_list_of_lists = []

        for v in list_of_lists:  # v::List[int]
            if value_to_check not in v:
                modified_list_of_lists.append(v)
            else:
                # modify list
                v_modified = []

                for val in v:  # val::int
                    if val == value_to_check:
                        v_modified.append(value_to_replace_with)
                    else:
                        v_modified.append(val)
                modified_list_of_lists.append(v_modified)
        return modified_list_of_lists
    else:
        return list_of_lists

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    # True
    print(is_value_in_list_of_lists(5, lists))
    # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 'X', 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    print(replace_all_occurrences_of_value_in_list_of_lists(5, "X", lists))
    # oneliner
    # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 'X', 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    print(list([*map(lambda x: "X" if x == 5 else x, y)] for y in lists))
```